# What is the term for how Star Wars characters have names based on real people, but scrambled?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, names, george-lucas

I distinctly remember there being a page on Wookieepedia on this.

For instance, taken from this [Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/How-did-George-Lucas-create-the-names-for-the-Star-Wars-characters/answer/Renee-Ocana)

> Bo-Katan is a portmanteau of Dave Filoni's wife's name (Anne) and her cat's name…
>
> Also, the Tooka species and Mar Tuuk from Clone Wars are named after Filoni's other cat, “Tuuk” (Dave really loves cats).

I think it was named after a particular person, sort of in honour of them. I've checked Wookieepedia and found nothing.

Comment: Coleman Kcaj and Nute Gunray come to mind as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known as [Tuckerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckerization) and [does have a page on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tuckerization).

> The term is derived from Wilson Tucker, a pioneering American science fiction writer, fan and fanzine editor, who made a practice of using his friends' names for minor characters in his stories. For example, Tucker named a character after Lee Hoffman in his novel The Long Loud Silence, and after Walt Willis in Wild Talent.

—  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckerization)